# No me crea mi BD en Express usando mongoose

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Tengo mi conexion aqui:

```
module.exports = function Connection(){

let db;

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    if (!db) {
        db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/crudExample')
        .then(db => console.log('DB is connected!'))
        .catch(err => console.log('ERROR al conectar la base de datos = ', err));
    }
    return db;
}
```

**User.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var db = require("../config/keys")();
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const UserSchema = Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  });
  return mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
};
```

Lo requiero en este **fichero** al llamar el model **User** :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//User model
const User = require("../models/user")();

//Login Page
router.get("/login", (req, res) => res.render("login"));

//Register Page

router.get("/register", (req, res) => res.render("register"));

//----------------------------------------------------------------

//Register Handle

    router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
      const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
      let errors = [];

      //Check required fields
      if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
        errors.push({
          msg: "Please fill in all fields"
        });
      }

      //Check password match
      if (password !== password2) {
        errors.push({
          msg: "Passwords do not match"
        });
      }

      //Check pass length

      if (password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({
          msg: "Password should be at least 6 characters"
        });
      }

      //si ha habido errores en la comprobacion
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render("register", {
          errors,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password2
        });
      } else {
        //Validation passed
        User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
          if (user) {
            //User exists
            errors.push({ msg: "Email is already registered" });
            res.render("register", {
              errors,
              name,
              email,
              password,
              password2
            });
          }else{
            const newUser = new User({
                name,
                email,
                password
            }); 
            console.log(newUser);
            res.send('hello'); 
          }
        });
      }
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Al registrarme con el formulario la pagina se queda **esperando respuesta del servidor** Luego compruebo en la terminal de node js si me ha creado la base de datos con nombre **crudExample** y no me lo ha creado. No encuentro que podria estar provocando el error.

Al mirar en la **consola de mongo** las bases de datos existentes no aparece la que estoy intentando crear: 

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes empezar revisando la uri: `'mongodb://localhost/crudExample'`. Te falta agregar el puerto `tcp` donde escucha Mongo. A menos que lo hayas cambiado al `80`. La uri debería ser: `'mongodb://localhost:27017/crudExample'`. Revisa eso y comentas.

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras he cambiado la URI tal cual me dijistes y posteriormente he mirado si me ha creado la base de datos en la consola, pero aun no me lo hace, debo decir tambien que cuando en el form del registro  registro un nuevo usuario se queda cargando el servidor igual

Comment: He añadido una captura de la terminal de mongo para que se vea que no esta creada

Comment: Tienes un problema en el primer módulo. `mongoose.createConnection` es asíncrona, tu función tiene un `return` que se ejecuta antes que la conexión se establezca. Para solucionarlo, mueve el `return db;` dentro del método `then()`. Puede quedar así:
`if (!db) {
    db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/crudExample')
        .then((db) => {
            console.log('DB is connected!');
            return db;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('ERROR al conectar la base de datos = ', err));
            return null;
        });
}`

Comment: Se mantiene el error. Estoy intentando hacer una traza para ver si consgo aclararlo, porque segun entiendo la conexion la usa el modelo y el modelo es requerido en las rutas, las rutas no deben usar la conexion directamente, no ?

Comment: Muéstrame el código donde usas tu módulo de conexión.

Comment: Está ya puesto. Es el primer fragmento de código

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91710/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-josanangel).

Comment: `newUser.save()` es lo que te falta hacer